# TeamCity Windows Tray Notifier stuck on "logged in"

Tags: teamcity-7.0

When I run the Windows Tray Notifier on my Windows 8 virtual machine, it remains stuck on a "logged in" message if I hover over the icon of the program in the system tray, and I can't do anything else other than force the shutdown with the Task Manager. I set the correct address where my TeamCity test server is running but it seems unable to connect to. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Fixed it via the following steps:

- Repaired via installer (this clears saved login data)
- Logged into a different server running Teamcity 6.5.3 - this worked
- logged out again and logged into our main teamcity server (running 7.1) - tray notifier is working again

Very strange! Above workaround would only work if you had access to a second server too.

**EDIT**: Two further workarounds have been posted on the thread I started on the Jetbrains forum, so I'll repost them here for the benefit of others.

Solution 1:

- Kill running tray notifier in task manager
- Open regedit, in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JetBrains\TeamCity\WindowsTray\Login, update the “S” property to `http://192.168.1.1:8080`  (substitute real ip address, without the quotes, trailing / seems to be important)
- Open IE, go to team city site
- Log in, checking “remember me”
- While IE is open and connected to TeamCity, start up tray notifier.
- Takes about 15 sec to change from “logging in” to connected.

Solution 2:

Open IE, select Internet Options, Security Tab, add the TeamCity server address to the trusted list.

Please note, I haven't personally tested either of these methods, just posting them here for information since others have found them to work. Hope this helps!

Since upgrading the server to 7.1.1 this issue hasn't reoccurred for me. Looks like it's been fixed as per Eugene's comment elsewhere on this thread.

Comment: I don't have any other TeamCity server but this is clearly a bug

Comment: Yeah agreed. I posted it up on the Teamcity forums here: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5466013#5466013

Noone has replied as yet...

Comment: I'm not registered on the TeamCity forums but I really hope someone will reply. Maybe the best thing to do here is open a bug report in their tracker

Comment: Just added a couple more potential solutions from the thread on the Jetbrains forum, hope these help Stefano!

Comment: For me, the trailing "/" was the key. I didn't need to do step 3, nor solution 2.

Comment: logging into IE first and then starting tray seems to work fine. Worst part is there is no context menu available until it can login to server. At least it should give an exit menu so I dont have to go kill it.

Comment: Solution 1 seemd to work for me. Not sure if I'll have to do this every time I restart my machine though?

Comment: Solution 1 did the trick for me. Thanks for figuring this out!

Answer (score 7):

This issue is definitely a bug in the tray notifier.

It isn't popping up login credentials, so

1. Log first into IE
2. Check remember me - try to save credentials
3. Close IE/Launch the notifier
4. It should be successful

Henry Wilson posted the [answer](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5466193#5466193) in their forums.  Hopefully it's fixed soon.

Comment: The bug is fixed for upcoming 7.1.1. See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23599

Comment: Still occurs for me on 8.1.5.  Workarounds here at least still work until you restart.  Seems to be a bug tracking the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-35234

Comment: This was a fix for me also running TeamCity Enterprise 9.1.7 (build 37573)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, the only difference is that it was stuck in "Loading..." and not in "Logging in...".

I added a trailing slash to the URL in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JetBrains\TeamCity\WindowsTray\Login" but it didn't help, so I deleted the whole tree "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JetBrains\TeamCity". After a restart of the application, it asked again for the URL.

I use 8.0.5 on the server. The tray notification reports "build NA" in the about window...

Comment: Ditto - killing the notifier process and deleting HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JetBrains\TeamCity\WindowsTray\Login\S seemed to be the only way to get past the stuck 'Loading...' message for me, 9.0.2 (build 32195)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this on:

Windows 7 - 64 bit,
TeamCity Pro 7.1 (build 23907)

All other effects are identical as above.

The suggestions above didn't work for me, but it did allow me to re-enter the server address.. still the problem persisted.

What worked for me was to remove then re-install in "Program Files" instead of the default "Program Files (x86)". There are a few reasons why this as-a-fix should be unnecessary, but it worked and I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- Open the CI-Server URL in Internet Explorer
- Log out from the CI-Server
- Restart the Tray Notifier (maybe kill via Taskamanger)
- Log in again

p.s. not sure if it is relevant, but for completeness:
I also added the CI-Server URL in the trusted sites in Internet Explorer → Internet Options (as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12001721/1520422)